# Java save simple Data

Tags: java, database, save, randomaccessfile

i need to save data from an java desktop application. The main part of the Data are the texts of around 50 labels. Which are spread over 5 Java GUI-classes. The Rest are some simple application settings.

Now i am quit unsure about how to safe these data. A friend told me to use Random access Data and to write some kind of "serializable" object. At the moment i am using a .txt and a fileReader/writer. But this seemes impractical for 50-100 Data if your want to search the position in the .txt by every update. This is my same problem with random access data. 
i thought about using some kind of embedded DB like "h2" but i dont now if this is to much and too complicated for such a small programm.

An other question is how do i put the text of all labels at the programm start. one way i am thinking about is to have a big list of all labels with determind positions and after reading the data from whatever to go over this list and set the labes. An other way would be to give every Label an id.
But maybe there is a much better way. But i dont now how to access the labels by names read from the data.

For saving serializable objects. Can i safe all the gui-object or do i need to combine se data in one class?

maybe someone could give a nice advise =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small number of labels, I would just keep all data in memory. On app initialization load the file and on every edit write the entire file from scratch

(If you are concerned about reliability in the face of power loss and random crashes during write you need to be careful here. For example, write the new data to a different file, fsync() then atomically rename the new file to the desired filename.)

I'm not sure I understand your serialization problem -- but it seems like you have some sort of language translation layer that tells the gui elements what to display. If so, then yes - I would store the labels in a central class (say `LablesMap`) and have the other classes refer to data in that class using some constant keys. E.g.,

```
myButton.setText(labelsMap.get(CANCEL_BUTTON_LABEL)
```

where `CANCEL_BUTTON_LABEL` is some constant or enum value.

Comment: mhm but give every label a name urrgh =D .. i just tried to put a list of Strings in that save class and every label takes at the start its text by id. or do you think its better to safe the labels in some kind of array in that class?

Comment: I would just use a `Map<Integer, String>` to store the labels. Serialize this map to disk on any edit and de-serialize it on startup.